# Json.Net Deserialize to JToken with Custom Contract Resolver

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

JSON.Net works well if I give a custom generic type to `Deserialize` method. But, when I change the output object type to `JToken`, it does not finish the deserialization process through the given serializer setting.

I must notify the deserializer that to put this property into that model property (e.g. => the property will be deserialized: `"date_add"` will be: `"DateAdd"` in the model). I do not want to use attributes.

When I debug my code below, `CustomContractResolver` does not work even when I put the breakpoint into there.

Here is my code:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(content,
            new JsonSerializerSettings() {ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver()});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for the custom resolver and also the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: You are correct, Json.NET does not use the contract resolver when parsing to a JToken.  The contract resolver is for reflection-based serialization but JToken is basically a literal parse tree of the JSON.  If you later deserialize the JToken to a POCO you can use the resolver then, e.g. `model.ToObject<RootObject>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() })); `  Can you show how you are using `model` after parsing?